# Static web site generator with big template/theme collection?

Tags: web, themes, generator

Any static web site generators (cms'es with export-to-html, or dedicated scripts) with big collections of templates/themes (**not for blogs**)?

Want to write how-to/wiki/tutorial website. (Created just by me)

1. Will edit website on my computer.
2. Will host static files on Amazon S3.
3. Hacking my own solution or using simple generators, fails when I need to make layout/design. That is just not my skill. (Hence "big template/theme collection" in title/question)

Answer (score 1):

After doing a Google search I came across this list https://iwantmyname.com/blog/2011/02/list-static-website-generators.html. The one that seemed to be what you where looking for was ikiwiki a wiki compiler that converts wiki pages into html. I would look at the themes on http://ikiwiki.info/theme_market/ an see what you like. Although this does not have a big collection of themes it seems that it was the best match to what you wanted. Also I believe there are a few themes shipped with the ikiwiki package although I am not sure how many. I would start there to see if what else you can find on that site.

Comment: +1 but ikiwiki have JUST 2 themes :D a bit small number and same quality

Comment: Yes, look at this page http://ikiwiki.info/themes/ its all the themes that come with ikiwiki by default.